# If there is an answer to a question I have but I don't understand it, should I ask a new question?

Tags: discussion

I was searching for the *difference between cloud and cluster*. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723040/what-is-the-difference-between-cloud-grid-and-cluster) question with a good answer, but I don't understand it.

If there is an answer to a question I have but I don't understand it, should I ask a new question?

Answer (score 3):

No.

First thing you could do is leave a comment to its author explaining to him/her that you don't understand a/b/c and d, and if they could explain it to you.

Secondly, you could start a bounty and choose the option **improve details**, and hopefully someone improves their answer or a new person comes a long with a more detailed and better to understand answer.

Comment: @rene I do have an account on SO.

Comment: You could use the question and answer as a starting point but you have to clearify what you DID understand and which part you didn't and why your research didn't resolved the question. Also note that the particular question is closed not constructive (today it would be too broad) and these type of questions might be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com but visit their meta first to see if that question would be on-topic there.